# AnimatedContainer is not working in one way

Tags: flutter, dart

I use `AnimatedContainer` in Flutter.

As you can see according to the value `selected`, the width and height value is changed.

```
class SubMenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool selected;
  final Widget imageWidget;
  final String topHeader;
  final String bottomHeader;

  const SubMenuWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.selected,
    required this.imageWidget,
    required this.topHeader,
    required this.bottomHeader,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              AnimatedContainer(
                width: selected ? 45 : 30,
                height: selected ? 45 : 30,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                curve: Curves.linear,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: isDarkMode(context)
                      ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)
                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                child: imageWidget,
              ),
              Gaps.h10,
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    topHeader,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: isDarkMode(context)
                          ? Colors.grey.shade400
                          : Colors.grey.shade600,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: Sizes.size15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    bottomHeader,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: isDarkMode(context)
                          ? Colors.white
                          : Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: Sizes.size18,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Gaps.v10,
            Container(
              color: isDarkMode(context)
                  ? Colors.grey.shade700
                  : Colors.grey.shade400,
              height: selected ? 2 : 1,
            ),
          ],
        ).animate().fadeIn(
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              duration: 1.5.ms,
            ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I change the `selected` value when tapping `GestureDetector` and pass that value as a parameter to `SubMenuWidget`.

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectedSubEventmenu = 0;
          });
        },
        child: SubMenuWidget(
          selected: _selectedSubEventmenu == 0,
          imageWidget: Image.asset(
            "assets/jpg/my-activity.png",
          ),
          topHeader: "1",
          bottomHeader: "one",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectedSubEventmenu = 1;
          });
        },
        child: SubMenuWidget(
          selected: _selectedSubEventmenu == 1,
          imageWidget: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/jpg/health.png",
            ),
          ),
          topHeader: "2",
          bottomHeader: "two",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

But when I click `SubMenuWidget` whose top header value is 2, Animation is applied well, but when I click  `SubMenuWidget` whose `topHeader` value is 1, Animation is not applied.

Why does this thing happen?

Comment: it's working for me, what's the issue?